# More efficient way of creating an array of months & revenue metrics?

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-access, visual-basic

I am relatively new to VBA and had a question about defining arrays.

I am writing a function in Microsoft Access to project five revenue metrics for the rest of year based on the most recent month's values.

I use two nested For...Next loops, an outer loop for revenue metrics, and an inner loop for the current month to end month. Within the inner loop I have a SQL query that utilizes counter values to append data to an output table.

Is there a better/condensed (more efficient) way to define the two arrays I have below?

```
Public Sub qapp_Revenue_Run_Rate()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim strSQL As String
Dim lng, lng2, counter, lngRRStart, lngMonth As Long

Dim month(1 To 12) As String
month(1) = "Jan"
month(2) = "Feb"
month(3) = "Mar"
month(4) = "Apr"
month(5) = "May"
month(6) = "Jun"
month(7) = "Jul"
month(8) = "Aug"
month(9) = "Sep"
month(10) = "Oct"
month(11) = "Nov"
month(12) = "Dec"

Dim metric(1 To 5) As String
metric(1) = "Investment Advisory Base Fees (ex-Sec Lending)"
metric(2) = "AUM Related Expenses"
metric(3) = "Securities Lending Revenue"
metric(4) = "Distribution & Other Revenue"
metric(5) = "BlackRock Solutions and advisory"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Array` function. It returns a `Variant`:

```
Dim month As Variant

month = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar" ...)
```

or you can use the format functiion

```
Dim month(1 To 12) As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 12
    month(i) = Format$(DateSerial(2017, i, 1), "mmm")
Next i
```

However, be aware that this returns months names according to culture defined in Windows. So on another PC this could return the names in another language.

---

A side-note: You declared

```
Dim lng, lng2, counter, lngRRStart, lngMonth As Long
```

In VBA and VB 6.0 the type declaration only applies to one variable. This means that all your variables on this line except `lngMonth` are of type `Variant`! You could write `lng = "hello"` and this runs without giving an error. You must write

```
Dim lng As Long, lng2 As Long, counter As Long, lngRRStart As Long, lngMonth As Long
```

In VB.NET this is no more the case, since there is no default type (`Variant` has been removed). So in VB.NET your `Dim` statement would be correct.